# Meteor bundle ignores folder and file

Tags: javascript, macos, amazon-web-services, meteor

There exists a app/main/document/temp.bin but this file is missing after I run `meteor bundle`.

When I ran `meteor bundle --debug` the file got put inside `bundle/programs/client/app/main/document/temp.bin`

so how can I make meteor bundle work?

Meteor version is 0.6.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run

```
meteor bundle something.tar.gz
```

Then in your meteor project's directory you would have the file `something.tar.gz` containing your project, ready for upload to a sever.

Don't forget to install fibers on your server. Once you've untarred:

```
cd bundle/programs/server/node_modules
rm -r fibers
npm install fibers@1.0.1
```